# Memory allocation for YUV buffer to convert into RGB

Tags: android, c++, c, video-streaming

I'm facing issue on few android devices while copying the data from DecodeFrame2()

This is my code:

```
uint8_t* m_yuvData[3];
SBufferInfo yuvDataInfo;
memset(&yuvDataInfo, 0, sizeof(SBufferInfo));
m_yuvData[0] = NULL;
m_yuvData[1] = NULL;
m_yuvData[2] = NULL;
DECODING_STATE decodingState = m_decoder->DecodeFrame2(bufferData, bufferDataSize, m_yuvData, &yuvDataInfo);

if(yuvDataInfo.iBufferStatus == 1)
{
        int yStride = yuvDataInfo->UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iStride[0];
        int uvStride = yuvDataInfo->UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iStride[1];
        uint32_t width = yuvDataInfo->UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iWidth;
       uint32_t height = yuvDataInfo->UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iHeight;
       size_t yDataSize = (width * height) + (height * yStride);
       size_t uvDataSize = (((width * height) / 4) + (height * uvStride));
        size_t requiredSize = yDataSize + (2 * uvDataSize);
        uint8_t* yuvBufferedData = (uint8_t*)malloc(requiredSize);
        // when i move yuvData[0] to another location i am getting crash.
         memcpy(yuvBufferedData, yuvData[0], yDataSize);
         memcpy(yuvBufferedData + yDataSize, yuvData[1], uvDataSize);
        memcpy(yuvBufferedData + yDataSize + uvDataSize, yuvData[2], uvDataSize);
  }
```

The above code snippet is working on high end android devices. but on few android devices after processing first frame, second frame onwards i am getting crash in first memcpy() statement.

What is wrong in this code? and how to calculate the buffer size from the output of DecodeFrame2().
If i process alternative frames(instead of 30, just 15 frames alternative ones), 
it is copying fine.

Please help me to fix this?

Comment: It could be me, but the memcpy that you're talking about takes yuvBufferedData and yuvData[0] as arguments, but you don't ever show us how these are defined or where the allocation happens... So, no... Can't help.

Comment: You have to show more code if you want to get useful answers.

Comment: This is for 640 * 480 resolution. I am receiving Frame from Camera, and uncompressing the frame(Demux)->decoding frame(H264)->YUVtoRGB conversion. These all happening in single thread. Till decode part its working fine. I've written the output of Decoder into .yuv file and played on YUV player. It is playing fine. But when i tried to Copy the output of Decode into another buffer(for YUV to RGB conversion), it is crashing on low end devices. First frame completing all the stages successfully. Second frame failing consistently.

Answer (score 0):

yDataSize and uvDataSize is very huge based on the above formula,
This issue has been fixed by modifying the size.